# Kolmogorov-Smirnov test strange output

Tags: goodness-of-fit, fitting, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, scipy

I am trying to fit my data to the one of the continuous PDF (I suggest it to be gamma- or lognormal-distributed). The data consists of about 6000 positive floats.
But the results of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test completely refute my expectations providing the very low p-values.

Data empirical distribution

[image]

Distribution fitting
[image]

Python code:

```
import numpy
import sys
import json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy
from scipy.stats import *

dist_names = ['gamma', 'lognorm']
limit = 30

def distro():
    #input file
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
        y = numpy.array(json.load(f))

    #output
    results = {}
    size = y.__len__()
    x = scipy.arange(size)
    h = plt.hist(y, bins=limit, color='w')
    for dist_name in dist_names:
        dist = getattr(scipy.stats, dist_name)
        param = dist.fit(y)
        goodness_of_fit = kstest(y, dist_name, param)
        results[dist_name] = goodness_of_fit
        pdf_fitted = dist.pdf(x, *param) * size
        plt.plot(pdf_fitted, label=dist_name)
        plt.xlim(0, limit-1)
        plt.legend(loc='upper right')
    for k, v in results.iteritems():
        print(k, v)
    plt.show()
```

This is the output:

- **p-value is almost 0** `'lognorm', (0.1111486360863001, 1.1233698406822002e-66)`
- **p-value is 0** `'gamma', (0.30531260123096859, 0.0)`

Does it mean that my data does not fit gamma distribution?.. But they seem so similar...

Comment: With so many data points, the standard error of the KS statistic is very small, and so the fact that it's visually a reasonable fit is irrelevant - the test can still tell it doesn't fit. But note that you're misapplying the Kolmogorov Smirnov test, since it's a test for a completely specified distribution and you're estimating parameters from the data. In any case it's not clear to me why you'd do a hypothesis test here. Do you really believe the true population distribution is exactly gamma or lognormal? Why? What would convince you of that rather than something else that looks like that?...

Comment: (ctd)... and if you think it's only an approximation, why  wouldn't you anticipate rejection in a large sample? If you're interested in 'is this a good approximation?' try looking at QQ plots, which will tell you where the devaitions occur and that may help you decide if it's 'near enough' for whatever purpose you'd want to specify an approximate distributional form for.

Comment: Thank you for responce. The aim of my work is the comparing of the several empirical distributions (kind of the one being discussed here). I wanted to use parametric methods in order to estimate the significance of the distribution parameters difference. But they seem to be restricted because of such a good results of fitting

Comment: Why use such simple parametric models when you have so much data?

Comment: Just a lack of knowledge... :) I would be appreciated if you give me advice about the modern methods of empirical distributions comparison.

Comment: It depends on what features/aspects of the distribution you're particularly interested in (such as location, spread, skewness, particular quantiles, tail index or whatever). If you're just interested in finding general differences, of course there are omnibus tests like a two sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test. If you want to reduce differences to a few easily described parameters, what you can do is start with a good approximation (such as gamma or lognormal), then use the approach of Smooth Tests of goodness of fit such as those that Rayner and Best have been working with, ...(ctd)

Comment: (ctd) ... where a family of orthogonal polynomials is used to characterize the deviations from that simple model. ... e.g. in the case of lognormal, it's easiest to take logs (going to a normal base model) and then fit models for data off orthogonal (Hermite) polynomials around that. You can characterize differences in terms of differences among low order terms. $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$ ... but it really depends on what you're interesting in finding out/comparing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.  Neither of these distributions is a good fit for your data by that criterion.  There are some other distributions you could try, but it strikes me as (ultimately) unlikely that real data come from any of the well-studied distributions, and you have 6k data, so even a trivial discrepancy will make the test 'significant'.  (For more along those lines, see: [Is normality testing 'essentially useless'?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/))

On the other hand, instead of checking to see if your data significantly diverge from these distributions, you could see how well your data *correlate* with the distributions you are interested in--the fit may well be 'good enough' for your purposes.  (For more along these lines, see my answer here: [Testing randomly generated data against its intended distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/27966/7290).)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your idea of a real-world and theoretical distributions principle discrepancy put me in a deadlock. But now I am inclined to accept your point of view, because I checked the goodness of fit for another 80 continuos PDF implemented in scipy.stats:

Comment: alpha  0.0

anglit  4.52300439976e-249

arcsine  0.0

beta  7.53500998959e-08

betaprime  0.0

bradford  0.0

burr  0.0

cauchy  0.0

chi  1.24814713547e-84

chi2  1.04723677282e-84

cosine  1.77417135669e-226

dgamma  1.48472973977e-152

dweibull  3.36030891852e-159

erlang  1.53825130531e-11

expon  8.49161219825e-20

exponpow  1.82371695398e-57

exponweib  0.00720597428858

f  0.0

fatiguelife  2.05556834159e-06

fisk  0.0
foldcauchy  0.0

foldnorm  1.21106424575e-143

frechet_l  0.0

frechet_r  6.96536022471e-14

Comment: gamma  0.0

gausshyper  0.0

genexpon  1.7330807758e-11

genextreme  0.0

gengamma  0.00696584086703

genhalflogistic  0.0

genlogistic  1.1266211972e-30

genpareto  0.0

gilbrat  1.12336984067e-66

gompertz  6.22010893728e-94

gumbel_l  0.0

gumbel_r  2.08089782821e-31

halfcauchy  0.0

halflogistic  5.08337633182e-16

halfnorm  1.52992191765e-143

hypsecant  1.63345582734e-124

invgamma  0.0

invgauss  0.000496831422071

invweibull  0.0

johnsonsb  1.53737964272e-249

johnsonsu  0.00132932660907

ksone  0.0

kstwobign  9.58783483152e-247

laplace  1.9692284069e-151

Comment: loggamma  7.41642157519e-285

logistic  1.33645347244e-117

loglaplace  0.0

lognorm  1.12336984067e-66

lomax  0.0

maxwell  1.41820716349e-144

mielke  0.0

nakagami  2.5747672096e-88

nct  7.42271600686e-06

ncx2  2.12122576081e-87

norm  4.20253225349e-189

pareto  0.0

powerlaw  0.0

powerlognorm  1.12338288177e-66

powernorm  0.0

rayleigh  3.96696047832e-164

rdist  4.09139833159e-145

recipinvgauss  1.88765428707e-07

reciprocal  0.0

rice  3.93163895411e-164

semicircular  3.04723581043e-278

t  2.33354811602e-100

triang  3.93993713488e-304

truncexpon  0.0

truncnorm  0.0

Comment: tukeylambda  1.2894110062e-134

uniform  8.91294425098e-321

vonmises  0.0

wald  3.69200293644e-06

weibull_max  0.0

weibull_min  6.96536022471e-14

wrapcauchy  0.0

Comment: As we can see, this empirical distribution can not be fitted anyway.

Comment: I would not be so pessimistic. The theoretical distributions are just models of reality, that is, they are simplifications of reality. Since "simplification" is just another word for "wrong in some useful way", we would not expect a model to fit perfectly. However, this is the null hypothesis of the KS-test. So the fact that all distributions differ significantly from the theoretical ones, does not tell us anything we did not know before we started the testing, especially in such large datasets.

Comment: The real question is whether your theoretical distribution is close enough to your data for your purpose. That is just a matter of looking where the discepancies are and decide whether or not those are relevant.

Comment: My purpose is the comparing of the several empirical distributions (kind of the one being discussed here). I wanted to use parametric methods in order to estimate the significance of the distribution parameters difference. Have no idea how to check it out now.

Comment: "*in order to estimate the significance of the distribution parameters difference*" --- why would you do that? What's the underlying problem of interest?

Comment: We would like to analyse spatial patterns of points distribution that came from one spatial model. Our point of interest is to study the behavior of the one, to determine the difference of outputs ceteris paribus.