# Fitting measured, real-world data to theoretical distribution: How to test goodness?

Tags: distributions, data-visualization, goodness-of-fit, fitting, weibull-distribution

I have a large sets of real-world user data (30k, 80k, 90k measurements). To be precise those are simply session lengths for a specific system. I want to create a theoretical model of this, to generate session lengths that roughly follow the distribution of the real-world session lengths (to be used in simulations).

I fitted the data to a Weibull distribution, which visually worked very well. When I create sample data from the Weibull distribution, using the parameters from the fitting, I get data that is very, very close.

However, when I want to test the goodness of the fit, things don't look so good. At first I used the K-S test (first value is D, second value is p-value)

```
K-S test            = (0.044257085422165915, 6.1787818394288534e-160)
2-sample K-S test   = (0.044934832227649907, 9.8401466055748469e-83)
```

The D-values are pretty low, which is nice. But the p-values are abysmal. Further research lead me to [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/27966), which - if I understand correctly - states, that a K-S test might not be the best tool for my case. The thing is, that the real-world data simply does not follow a specific, theoretical distribution. So the p-values *should* be low. What I want is just a distribution that generates values that are *pretty close* to the real world data.

Is there any renowned test that supports me in finding a distribution that is *pretty close*?

Comment: The answer you link to suggests estimating a correlation (between sample & theoretical quantiles) rather than performing a test - I'm not quite sure how it doesn't already answer your question. Indeed, aren't the K-S test statistic values you've calculated already telling you in one sense how close the empirical distribution is to the theoretical?

Answer (score 1):

You would<most often be better off using a Weibull plot for assessing distribution fit, see [Weibull plot to assess goodness of fit](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/551947/weibull-plot-to-assess-goodness-of-fit).

If you rather want/need a formal goodness of fit test, see [A goodness of fit test for the Weibull distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/420441/a-goodness-of-fit-test-for-the-weibull-distribution), but the advice at  [Is normality testing 'essentially useless'?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless)  would equally apply for Weibull testing, as for normal testing.